# ActionScript: loading variables from a text file into _root

Tags: flash, actionscript, loadvars

I'm basically a noob in `ActionScript`, and I've run into a problem. I want to load variables from a text file into the `_root` of my movie. Like, the text file contains `&var=value&var2=value2&` , and I want them to go straight into `_root` so that I'd be able to call them as `_root.var` and `_root.var2`.
First, I tried using the obvious solution, **loadVariables**. I've done it through the following function:

```
function getState (save){
    //loadVariables("getstate.php?save="+save, "/");
    loadVariables("state.txt, "/");
}
```

I've tried loading it to "`_root`" instead of "`/`", but still nothing. The request gets sent, but the contents of the text file get lost in hyperspace on their way to my code.

So I tried using LoadVars instead of loadVariables. This function disappointed me because there wasn't the option of dumping the vars right into `_root`, but I decided to try it anyway. Here's how my function looks like with LoadVars:

```
function getState (save){
    varReceiver = new LoadVars();
    varReceiver.onLoad = function(){
        varsRecieved=true;
        _root.notloggedin = this.notloggedin;
        _root.nostate = this.nostate;
        _root.saveName=this.saveName;
        //and lots of other variables
        trace (_root.saveName);
    };
    varReceiver.load("state.txt");
    trace (_root.saveName);
}
```

The trace that is inside the onLoad function returns the correct value, but the one after it returns undefined. I've tried waiting for the onLoad to happen with this loop:

```
while (varsRecieved != true){
    trace ("not yet...");
}
```

Which sent **Flash** into an endless loop.

I'd really appreciate some help on this matter =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code that needs to be executed after the information has been loaded in a separate function and call that function at the end of the `onLoad` handler:

```
function getState (save){
    varReceiver = new LoadVars();
    varReceiver.onLoad = function(){
        _root.notloggedin = this.notloggedin;
        _root.nostate = this.nostate;
        _root.saveName=this.saveName;
        //and lots of other variables
        trace (_root.saveName);
        doRest();
    };
    varReceiver.load("state.txt");
}

function doRest()
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that `getState()` will return before the information has been loaded, so existing code may have to be moved to `doRest()`.

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't help me much, as the code that needs to e executed after  the information has been loaded is strewn all over my movie and can't possibly be fit into one function.